# Loop for Data Management

Tags: loops, stata, data-manipulation

For the dataset like the following

I want to change the value of `G7_A6` which is either 1 or 2 based on `B1_04`. For a given ID (there are two same IDs) `G7_A6` takes either only 1 or only 2.

I need to use loops in Stata [enter image description here][1] because I have a very large dataset and typing individual IDs is cumbersome

```
replace G7_A6="2" if B1_04=="3" | B1_04 =="4" | B1_04 == "5" | B1_04 =="6" |B1_04 =="7"
replace G7_A6="1" if B1_04=="2"
```

The link of picture is here
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv7RI.png

Comment: You say you want to generalise this, but there is no information here on any other variables or how you want to do that.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1607154-stata-loop-for-data-management  It is always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop program for this, as each relationship is row-specific. The code you are using would solve your problem but is a bit cumbersome. A cleaner version would be:

```
replace G7_A6 = 2 if B1_04 != 1 | B1_04 != 2
replace G7_A6 = 1 if B1_04 == 1 | B1_04 == 2
```

This will give you the following data:

| id | name | B1_04 | G7_A6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sam | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | margaret | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | Jim | 5 | 2 |
| 9 | Cinderella | 1 | 1 |

You did not post a question either: you simply said you need a program to do what you already posted.

Comment: Note also the scope for using `inlist()` as in `!inlist(B1_04, 1, 2)`. OP's code implies that variable to be string, but the same applies to `!inlist(B1_04, "1", "2")`.

Comment: Correct, something I left out when testing in stata. I just think it's madness to have an integer list coded as strings unnecessarily. It's hard to comment on though since the question is so "mysterious" for lack of better words.

Comment: We really can't tell. Perhaps the OP really needs and really has more complicated strings and is just showing a simple example. On other grounds that is welcome/

Comment: I want to use replace command (condition) to change G7_A6 for sam, Jim, George, etc who are males such that G7_A6 for Margaret, Cinderella, Natalie etc (who are females) also takes the value of Sam, Jim, George, etc. B1_04 for females is always 1 while value of B1_04 for males varies from 2 to 7. I hope I have made it clearer this time. Is this kind of operation possible in STATA

Comment: If G7_A6 =1 for ID=1 and Name = Sam, then for ID=1 and Name=Margaret, G7_A6 should automatically equal to 1. and so on for other IDs